# Unity Raycast going through walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an fps game, and I made a level with Probuilder. The enemies shoot a raycast in the player direction, but they hit the player no matter what's in the way.

Here's the code that I'm using for the enemy raycast, all the layers are set. The probuilder cube is using mesh collider, but I tried with the deafult unity cubes and that doesnt work either. (FireProjectile function isn't in use)

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Enemy Settings")]
    bool canShoot, isDead;
    Vector3 playerDir;
    [Header("Enemy Type")]
    [Space]
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    RaycastHit hit, shotHit;
    PlayerMovement playerM;
    public AudioSource enemyShot;
    public AudioClip gunS;
    public ParticleSystem enemyFlash;
    float timer;
    public GameObject projectilePrefab, debugSpot;
    public float Health, shootRange, noticeRange, bulletSpeed, shotCooldown, stopDistance, shotDamage;
    public LayerMask playerLayer;
    public Transform player, enemyBarrel;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerM = player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Health <= 0f)
        {
            Death();
        }

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
        playerDir = player.position - transform.position;
        if ((distance <= noticeRange) && !isDead)
        {
            transform.LookAt(player.position);
            if (distance >= stopDistance)
            {
                agent.isStopped = false;
                agent.SetDestination(player.position);
            }
            else
            {
                agent.isStopped = true;
            }
        }

        if (distance > noticeRange)
        {
            timer = 0f;
        }

        if (timer >= shotCooldown)
        {
            canShoot = true;
        }
        if(timer <= shotCooldown)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime * 2f;
            canShoot = false;
        }

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, playerDir, out hit, shootRange, playerLayer) && canShoot && !isDead)
        {
            Shoot();
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }


    }

    // AI CODE
    void Shoot()
    {
        enemyFlash.Play();
        enemyShot.PlayOneShot(gunS);
        timer = 0f;
        // Calculate the player's predicted position
        Vector3 playerVelocity = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
        //float distanceFromPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
        float timeToReachPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position) / shootRange;
        Vector3 predictedPosition = player.position + playerVelocity/3f * timeToReachPlayer;

        Vector3 dir = predictedPosition - transform.position;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dir, out shotHit, shootRange, playerLayer))
        {
            shotHit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().Damage(shotDamage);
            Instantiate(debugSpot, shotHit.point, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        //FireProjectile(predictedPosition);
    }

    void FireProjectile(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        // Instantiate and launch the projectile towards the target position
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Rigidbody projectileRigidbody = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Calculate the direction towards the target position
        Vector3 direction = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;

        // Launch the projectile towards the target position
        projectileRigidbody.velocity = direction * bulletSpeed;
        Destroy(projectile, 5f);
    }

    // AI CODE

    public void Damage(float dmg)
    {
        Health -= dmg;
    }

    public void Death()
    {
        isDead = true;
        agent.enabled = false;
        transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = false;
        Destroy(gameObject, 3f);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, player.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: The LayerMask determines the objects which can collide with Raycast. In Player Layer select all layers except the layers of the enemy, so ray from the enemy cannot collide with itself. [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html)

Comment: And then check if the hit object is the player?

Comment: Yes, just change the layers in the editor, you don't need to change anything in script.

Answer (score 1):

Do another physics raycast and check for any obstacles in the player direction.
If that raycast is true, the player is behind a wall or something.